# Getting Cors Error when making api calls in angular

Tags: angular, spring-boot, spring-boot-security

I have written my backend in spring boot and running on (localhost:9090) and the frontend is running on angular (localhost:4200).

I am facing this issue when trying to get data from the backend.

**Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:9090/vendor-data/' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.**

This is the Service file -

```
  getVendorData(headersData:any):Observable<any>{
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:9090/vendor-data/',{headers:headersData});
  }
```

This is the component.ts file -

```
ngOnInit() {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({
      Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
    });
    console.log(this.data.getVendorData(headers))
    this.data.getVendorData(headers).subscribe({
      next: (v) => {
        this.vendorList = v;
      },
      error: (e) => {},
      complete: () => { },
    });
  }
```

This is the config file in the backend -

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class VendorConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
         registry.addMapping("/**").allowedOrigins("http://localhost:4200")
         .allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE")
             .allowCredentials(true);                                                                               
    }
}
```

I also tried using @CrossOrigin("*") in the Controller file but I am still getting the same issue.

```
public class DataFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter{
    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        
        String token=extractToken(request);
        boolean isError=true;
        
        if(token!=null && token.length()>6) {
            try {
                Jwts
                .parserBuilder()
                .setSigningKey(Keys.hmacShaKeyFor(Decoders.BASE64URL.decode(
                        "f9b2b91e3c468f1937598573b00d923426127dc06bf6cc8b446fac9ec1364f88")))
                .build()
                .parseClaimsJws(token)
                .getBody();
                isError=false;
                filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
            }
            catch(SignatureException e) {
                System.out.print("Invalid Signature");
            }
            catch(MalformedJwtException e) {
                System.out.print("Invalid Token");
            }
        }
        if(isError) {
            (response).sendError(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED.value(),"Unauthorized");
        }
    }

    private String extractToken(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String authHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization");
        String token = null;
        if (authHeader != null) {
            token = authHeader.substring(7);
        }
        return token;
    }
```

Is this filter class causing the errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just added this to the api-gateway

```
@Bean
public CorsWebFilter corsWebFilter() {
    CorsConfiguration corsConfig = new CorsConfiguration();
    corsConfig.addAllowedOrigin("*");
    corsConfig.addAllowedMethod("*");
    corsConfig.addAllowedHeader("*");
    corsConfig.setAllowCredentials(true);

    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", corsConfig);

    return new CorsWebFilter(source);
}
```

and it removed the cors error

Answer (score -2):

The CORS issue you're encountering is related to the security restrictions enforced by web browsers when making cross-origin requests. To resolve this issue, you need to configure CORS properly in both your Spring Boot backend and Angular frontend. Here's what you can do:

#### Backend (Spring Boot):

1. **Use `@CrossOrigin` Annotation**: Make sure to annotate your controller methods with `@CrossOrigin` to allow requests from your Angular frontend. For example:

   ```java
   @RestController
   @CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
   public class VendorController {
       // Controller methods
   }
   ```

   Ensure that this annotation is applied to all the relevant controller methods or controllers.
2. **Configure CORS Globally (Optional)**: If you prefer to configure CORS globally, you can do this in your `VendorConfiguration` class as you've shown. However, your current configuration seems correct. Ensure that this class is being scanned and applied by Spring Boot.
3. **CORS Filter**: You can also create a global CORS filter as an alternative approach. Here's an example of a CORS filter:

   ```java
   import org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter;

   @Component
   public class CorsConfig {

       @Bean
       public CorsFilter corsFilter() {
           UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
           CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
           config.setAllowCredentials(true);
           config.addAllowedOrigin("http://localhost:4200");
           config.addAllowedHeader("*");
           config.addAllowedMethod("*");
           source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
           return new CorsFilter(source);
       }
   }
   ```

#### Frontend (Angular):

1. **Use the Angular Proxy (Recommended)**: When developing locally, it's a good practice to use the Angular CLI proxy to avoid CORS issues. You can configure it by adding a `proxy.conf.json` file in your Angular project's root directory:

   ```json
   {
     "/api": {
       "target": "http://localhost:9090",
       "secure": false
     }
   }
   ```

   Then, when making API requests in your Angular code, use relative URLs like `/api/vendor-data` instead of the full URL. The Angular CLI will handle the proxying for you.
2. **CORS Headers**: Ensure you're setting the correct headers in your Angular service when making requests. You've already done this correctly.

With these configurations, your Angular frontend should be able to communicate with your Spring Boot backend without CORS issues during development. When deploying to production, make sure to configure CORS in your server environment accordingly to match your production setup.

Comment: Yup that is right, you can also configure it in properties files, i deal with this often and I still question the purpose why CORS helps, cross origin what can it fix or make more secure?

Comment: @MadukaJ I tried everything that you mentioned and still nothing would work